# Update CRM 2011 Access Right Programmatically

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I would like to know if there is some way to update an Access Right in CRM 2011.

Let's say I have an Access Right named Marketing Manager which has user level privilege to create Account, I'd like to change this privilege to Organization level programmatically.

I'm waiting hopefully,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the code below. However it actually copy Role Privileges from existing Role to new Role. But I think it can give you an idea.

```C#
Guid existingRoleId = new Guid("C85F0FFF-4C80-E211-A877-1CC1DE79B4CA");
Guid newRoleId = new Guid("B6690FFF-4C80-E211-A877-1CC1DE79B4CA");

// Step 2
RetrieveRolePrivilegesRoleRequest getPrivilagesRequest = 
                 new RetrieveRolePrivilegesRoleRequest();

getPrivilagesRequest.RoleId = existingRoleId;
RetrieveRolePrivilegesRoleResponse privilagesResponse = 
         (RetrieveRolePrivilegesRoleResponse)service.Execute(getPrivilagesRequest);

if (privilagesResponse != null && privilagesResponse.RolePrivileges != null)
{
    // Step 3
    AddPrivilegesRoleRequest addPrivilagesRequest = new AddPrivilegesRoleRequest();
    addPrivilagesRequest.Privileges = privilagesResponse.RolePrivileges;
    addPrivilagesRequest.RoleId = newRoleId;
    AddPrivilegesRoleResponse addPrivilagesResponse = 
            (AddPrivilegesRoleResponse)service.Execute(addPrivilagesRequest);
}
```

Ref: [Copy a security role programmatically – CRM 2011](http://rajeevpentyala.wordpress.com/2013/05/21/copy-a-security-role-programmatically-crm-2011/)

[Link 2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151187.aspx)

Comment: Firstly, thank you for the quick answer.Secondly I do appreciate your attempt to give me an idea, but I really didn't get the point, in this code he just copied the access without change anything.

Comment: Honestly I don't know if we can update privileges or not. But I think you can use workaround if there is no other option. Create a Role called "New Role" with Organization level privileges. When you want to update a role privileges. Copy the privileges from "New Role" to the role you want to update. I have also updated the answer, please check the link 2 as well. Regards

Comment: Unfortunately none of these tips helped me. Anyway, I'm guessing it's impossible, thanks