# How do I create a custom entity that can be read by all users?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Is there a quick way to mark a custom entity as readable by all users via a Customizations.xml entry?

I have been successful in creating the custom entity I need, but cannot seem to make it readable by newly created users without creating a security role (with read permissions for the entity) and applying it to ALL users.

Is there a way I can ensure that everyone (even newly created users) have read access to a custom entity?

Comment: According to the documentation noted by Draiden, this is not an option for custom entities.  All custom entities are assigned accessible by default to the System Administrator, other security roles will need to manually add read / write access to entity in order to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry the question, but why do you need an Entity for each user that is readable by everyone?
I mean is not the same to create a record in one entity and filter it with custom views if you want to?

Comment: The entity that is created belongs to the organization, not each individual user.  I want it to be readable by everyone so they can access the data stored in it.

Comment: Hi Maixy, try to consider the creation of a team or a traversal role.

Comment: Hi Draiden,  I realize I could create a role and assign it to EVERY user, but I am really looking for a way to simply have the read permissions on an entity be open for all.  Judging by the way that people keep misunderstanding that, I'm guessing that this just isn't possible in Dynamics CRM.

Comment: I don't think i get your situation :S Create a new entity for each user seems unnecessary. But if you are still going for it, consider to create a team with all the users inside and assign the role with the permissions on the new entity on team level (so manually the admin needs to add only 1 permission in one role for each user that will be created). To manage the teams you can go with a plugin on creation and assign the user to the team with the permissions on the new entity. You can even apply the solution that the people suggested under here, but that will involve a lot of manual work :S

Comment: Well last choice that you have is to try to edit the security roles on user creation. I actually never tried it but is the closest thing that you can do if you want to open an entity to all the users http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959505/update-crm-2011-access-right-programmatically try to read this and see if it helps

Comment: Again, I'm not creating an entity for EACH user.  I've mentioned this above. I'm creating one entity, and I want it to be available to all users, newly created or existing.  If I go with a team or security role approach, that requires additional steps each time a new user is added (they have to be given the new role or be assigned to the new team).  I just figured it would be a reasonable thing for CRM to allow entities to be readable by all users if that was the desired trait.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding :) you are right, you can't do it without editing the security roles. The configuration books are mentioning that if you add a new entity, will be available only to the sys admin and the configurator (but i'm not sure on the name of the second security role), so only for 2 roles, for the others you will need to do the update manually.

Answer (score 1):

Users need at least one role to be able to log in, so I'd suggest to create one common role that is assigned to everyone. Then you can grant permission to read your entity in this common role.

This approach might help you also in future, when you'll have to allow access to other entities for everyone.

Comment: Unfortunately this still requires that all users are given this additional security role.  I'm unable to assign this role to each new user as they are created, so all newly created users will still seem broken when accessing the custom entity.

Comment: @Maixy: User access to CRM is blocked until they have role assigned, therefore to allow them to use system you need to assign at least one role anyway.

Comment: I see your point, but as a plugin I think it's a bit awkward to expect system administrators to manually assign a custom security role to each of their users (new and old).  It would be wonderful if there were a way to simply allow certain entities created by the plugin to have unrestricted read permissions

Comment: You got me confused. In your plugin do you create new entity (table) or new record in existing table? If we are talking about new entities (tables) you can modify roles in your plugin, to append read permission to newly created table (see AddPrivilegesRoleRequest message)

Comment: I am adding a new entity, but was hoping to be able to simply allow it to be readable via the customizations.xml rather than have its Read privilege restricted by default and requiring the admin to run through numerous programmed requests to CRM to update all roles with the necessary read permissions.